# What is the easiest way avoid sending the Tomcat error page with Spring MVC @RequestMapping?

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

I've tried this a couple of different ways, including @ExceptionHandler,  and using HttpServletResponse as a parameter to the mapped method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> update(final HttpEntity<String> requestEntity) {
    try {
        // stuff
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    } catch (MyDataException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.toJSONString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

All I want is the contents of toJSONString as the response body. However, with the HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST value set, the system uses the default Tomcat error page. If I don't set it to an error status, it creates the body as I intend it. But I must set the error status.

As I said, I've tried this about four different ways in the Spring MVC API, and they all end up looking like sendError() is called instead of handling the response in the way that I want.

Comment: Would this really be a 400 Error? Looks like it's connecting to the server just fine, but there was a database issue.  Wouldn't that be an application level exception, not a server exception?

Comment: It's not having trouble with the database, there's something wrong with the input parameters that only the database can determine. Also, a 400 error is an application-level exception, because HTTP is an application-level protocol.

Comment: Right, so wouldn't this be business logic? The database is expecting certain parameters from the call, but not getting them.  400 is related to resolving IP addresses, opening sockets, etc. http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

Comment: No, HTTP 400 is http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1 -- "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax." 

Errors in resolving hostnames and opening sockets are transport-layer errors. They don't have an HTTP error code because HTTP is an application layer protocol.

Comment: Very interesting, good to know.  The definition is quite broad, however, but I can see now how you were trying to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a case of PEBKAC, or rather failing to recognize that a poorly written http proxy was actively replacing the response body with a Tomcat error page.